# To use Azure Queue for SendGrid, or not?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am looking to use SendGrid to send emails based on some trigger(S) within an application. Should the application invoke SendGrid API calls to send emails, or should it send emails to Azure Queue and have some other process send the email from Azure, like an Azure micro service?